# Want to add ImageView or FLoatingActionButton beside FAB in side CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I want to add ImageView or FAB to bottom right of FAB button which stay over AppBarLayout and when i scroll that Image or FAB also should hide just like FAB button .

Here is Screen shot where i want to put my ImageView or FAB.

[image: You can see Info icon below right side of FAb blue button]

Now problem ares

1.Info image which is below right side of Floating Button it should be much close to FAb button

2.When i scroll then Info image also should be hide just like that FAB blue button .Currently when i scroll that Info icon go to screen Bottom right side .

Comment: Is this you wanted? https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

Comment: No , In Screen Shot you can see Info icons which should be also gone when i Scroll Up my RecycleView ,Currently it just hide The Blue FAb only.I want same effect to Info gray icons which is below that Blue FAB.